Is there a way to search previous runs within a logicapp, as part of the logicapp?
I am trying to solve a problem where data we receive may be duplicated. We do not have a search API available to search the database, so I wondered if there is a way to use the logicapp to search previous runs for that app and send an error message if they find that a field is duplicated (it will only be one field from the dataset).
We receive data in the body, for example
id1: 123
id2: 456
id3: 789
The client's system has a hole where id2 = 456 may be sent multiple times although it should be unique. We would normally add steps to run a search via API for the value against existing id2s in our data, but this is not an option. So I wanted to know if we could run some kind of lookup step within the logicapp to check the runtime repository for that specific app.
(I am not a dev, please forgive the non tech explanation)
N/A - I haven't been able to test anything


Is there a way to search previous runs within a logicapp, as part of the logicapp?

To get details of previous run, only way is by using Logs of runs. Firstly set the diagnostic settings to a Log analytics workspace in Logic app as below:

Then in Log Analytics Workspace in Workspace add :

To test logs:
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.LOGIC"
| where OperationName has "workflowRunCompleted"


Then in Logic app Design you can use below action to get the results of previous runs in Design itself:

In above action you can use the kql query given to get the details. You can only get the logs and not complete details of each action of Design

I would also recommend using Custom Tracking Id or Tracked properties to find the exact run that contains the required ID
